# Propiedad height dinámica en componente p:progressbar

Tags: java, css, primefaces

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con primefaces 6 en la que utilizo un componente `p:progressbar` para indicar el progreso de una operación. La propiedad `labelTemplate` de la barra de progreso muestra una descripción de la operación en cuestión.

```
<p:progressBar 
  id="progresoOperacion-#{operacionBean.id}"
  value="#{operacionBean.progreso}"
  labelTemplate="#{operacionBean.descripcion}"/>
```

La aplicación está diseñada bajo la premisa *responsive*, por lo que el diseño debe adaptarse adecuadamente.

En definitiva, mi problema reside en que en ciertos tamaños la descripción contenida en la barra de progreso se muestra en más de una línea, pero el alto del progressbar no se adapta a dicho alto.

La siguiente imagen muestra la descripción con la barra de progreso en un tamaño en el que se ve adecuadamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La siguiente imagen muestra el problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo hacer que se adapte el alto del progressbar en base al alto que proporcione el texto de la propiedad `labelTemplate`?

Comment: No puedo probarlo ahora pero quizas con un `style="height: auto;"` o algo así podría funcionar

Comment: Cuando establezco la propiedad `height: auto;` la barra de progreso desaparece.